# When I try to sculpt instead of it working normally small triangles appear on my model where I tried to sculpt

Tags: sculpting

When I try to sculpt instead of it working normally small triangles appear on my model where I tried to sculpt. I have no idea why this is happening, it only happens for one object in my blender scene. I checked to see if it was a setting for the actual sculpt tool which I had accidentally changed and its not, anyone got any ideas on how to fix this issue?

[image: This is a picture of what sculpt brush does why I try to sculpt]

Comment: Is Dyntopo activated (top right corner between symmetry and remesh options)?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of what you mean by it working normally? This actually looks regular to me.

Comment: Yes dyntopo is on but it is still buggy even if it isn't enabled and will still just create the small triangles in the picture above wherever I try to sculpt.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. You just need to embed a smaller object inside the mesh and use the [`Bool Tool`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/object/bool_tools.html) to join them together. Then the [`Sculpting Tools`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/sculpt_paint/sculpting/tools.html) will work properly again.